# SQL query to get customer status against their orders

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone help me to get the SQL query with below conditions?

We have customer and their orders date.

- New single: customer who is no there before in file made their first purchase and only one purchase for the whole year (customer can make multiple purchase on same day).
- New multi: customer who are new to file, but made multiple purchases in the whole year
- Reactive: customer who made purchase with year gap from order date
- Active new: customer who made purchase in previous year and current year but does not hold active status in previous years
- Active evergreen: customer who made purchase in previous year and current year but hold active status previous years.

Please find below sample data DDL Customer string, orderdate date

```
customer    Orderdate       output
C1          Mar-16      New Mul  (New Multi bcz customer first time ordered and ordered multiple time in same year if ordered only one day then it ould be New )
C1          Oct-16      New Mul
C1          Apr-17      Active --Ordered last year and no active status previous
C1          Dec-18      Active Evergreen  ---ordered last year and already active before
C1          Sep-17      Active
C1          May-20      Reactive--- Last year not ordered
C1          Apr-21      Active Evergreen  ----ordered last year and already active before
```

Comment: Sounds like what you need is the SELECT CASE statement.

Comment: And some subqueries. This is achievable, but it will be fairly complex.

Comment: Yes.. I tried but unable to get the desired results

Comment: can you share your query

Comment: Can you add the layout of the `customer_data` table? So we can see what columns it has? (I infer that `customer_data` is the only table you need for this, based on your query in the answer.)

Comment: How can we tell, from the data, whether a customer has active status in a prior year? How are you defining active status?

Comment: Customer Data has only 2 column (customer and orderdate.)

Comment: Each customer  will start from New or New Mul bcz after that we have to check the other sttaus

Comment: What other status?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below query

```
with cth as (
select a.customer, a.ORDERDATE ,
case  when a.row_nm=1 and yr=min_yr then 'New'
  when a.row_nm>1 and yr=min_yr then 'New Ultimate'
  when a.row_nm>=1 and yr=min_yr+1 then 'Active'
  when a.row_nm>=1 and (yr-yr2 )>=2 then 'Reactive'
end as status
FROM


(select customer ,orderdate , extract (year from orderdate ) as yr ,
row_number() over (partition by customer, extract (year from orderdate )  order by orderdate asc ) as row_nm
from customer_Data)  a 

inner join ( select customer , min (extract (year from orderdate ) ) as min_yr
 from customer_data group by customer) b 
 on a.customer=b.customer

 inner join ( select customer, yr2 ,  rank() over (partition by customer order by yr2 desc) as rnk FROM
 (select customer , extract(year from orderdate) yr2 from customer_data group by customer,extract(year from orderdate)) 
  d
 )c on b.customer=c.customer )
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Is this an answer or clarification of you question? If its your attempt, but not an answer, please move it into your question.

Comment: Yes.. this is my attempt not an accurate solution.